# Get parent SKU (configurable or bundle) from child SKU Magento 2

Tags: php, magento2

On the order page(backend) I need to be able to obtain the parent SKU using a child SKU.

I've tried several code snipped from both the Magento forums and similar questions here on StackOverflow without success.

I'm able to determine if a product is just a simple product without a parent by using `getTypeId()` but after that everything I try fails to result in getting at the parent SKU.

Magento 2.2.6

Comment: Magento has its own stack exchange with lots of great thorough answers from magento professionals. https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

Configurable, bundle and grouped are all different and require different means to get their parents. The methods are listed within the relevant files.

**Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable.php**

```
/** 
* Retrieve configurable parent ids array by required child
*
* @param  int|array $childId
* @return array
*/
public function getParentIdsByChild($childId)
{
   return $this->_catalogProductTypeConfigurable->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
}
```

**Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type.php**

```
/**
* Retrieve bundle parent ids array by required child
*
* @param int|array $childId
* @return array
*/
public function getParentIdsByChild($childId)
{
   return $this->_bundleSelection->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
}
```

**Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped.php**

```
/**
* Retrieve grouped parent ids array by requested child
*
* @param int|array $childId
* @return array
*/
public function getParentIdsByChild($childId)
{
   return $this->productLinks->getParentIdsByChild(
       $childId,
       \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_GROUPED
  );
}
```

Lastly, in case you need to quickly get the sku from mysql .

```
#Select parent of a sku
 SELECT
  parent.sku
FROM
  catalog_product_entity parent
WHERE parent.row_id =
  (SELECT
    relationship.parent_id
  FROM
    catalog_product_super_link relationship
  WHERE relationship.product_id =
    (SELECT
      child.entity_id
    FROM
      catalog_product_entity child
    WHERE child.sku = "SKU")
  );
```

Comment: I am trying Retrieve bundle parent ids follow your way but this alway return array empty. Maybe it's wrong

Comment: @huykon225 not sure about the code, but the query needs to be edited to work. 
There is no such field as 'row_id', I think he meant 'entity_id'. 
This worked for me: 


 SELECT
  parent.`entity_id`,
  parent.`sku`
FROM
  catalog_product_entity parent
WHERE parent.`entity_id` =
  (SELECT
    relationship.parent_id
  FROM
    catalog_product_super_link relationship
  WHERE relationship.product_id =
    (SELECT
      child.entity_id
    FROM
      catalog_product_entity child
    WHERE child.sku = "SKU")
  );

Comment: @MohammedJoraid, row_id is actually from Adobe Commerce ( the enterprise version). entity_id still exists, but row_id is correct.

Comment: @willboudle yes, that is correct. Thank you for the updates. As you said the row_id is available on newer Adobe Commerce EE version.  Mine is CE and bit older so I don't have the row_id. 

Does that mean the SKU is no longer the unique identifier for the entity product?

Comment: @MohammedJoraid, because Adobe Commerce has scheduling capabilities, there are two identifiers. entity_id and row_id. entity_id will never actually change on a sku, they are a 1:1. But row_id is 1:many. A sku could have scheduled changes, and row_id reflects that.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278051/row-id-vs-entity-id-in-magento-2-3-ee

Comment: @willboudle thank you sir for the valuable info. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query that you can do for multiple SKUs
I hope that helps you

`select parent.row_id,parent.entity_id,parent.sku  from catalog_product_entity parent WHERE parent.row_id IN ( SELECT child.parent_id from catalog_product_super_link child WHERE child.product_id IN ( select child.entity_id from catalog_product_entity child WHERE child.sku IN('CHILDSKU1','CHILDSKU2') ) )`